# Django rest serializer problem with serializing many-to-many field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I cannot serialize menu object, which contains foreign key to DishOrder object which contains a foreign key to Dish object.

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    dishes = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, through="DishOrder")

    @property
    def cost(self):
        return self.dishes.aggregate(total_cost=Sum('dish__price'))['total_cost'] or 0.00

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Меню '{self.name}'"
```

```
class DishOrder(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dish.name
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class DishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.category', read_only=True)
    price = serializers.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dish
        fields = '__all__'


class DishOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dish = DishSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = DishOrder
        fields = ['dish', 'quantity']



class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = DishOrderSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = '__all__'
```

Error after calling MenuSerializer(all_menus)

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `dish` on serializer `DishOrderSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Dish` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Dish' object has no attribute 'dish'.
```

ChatGPT says: the problem may occur because of dish naming

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```py
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = DishOrderSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = '__all__'
```

`dishes` is a FK relationship to `Dish` class so it's expecting a `DishSerializer` serializer

change it to

```py
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = DishSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = '__all__'
```